# iMessage Extension and CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3, imessage

I am trying to read **CoreData** out of an **iMessage Extension** (MSMessagesAppViewController) but as there is no AppDelegate there is also no `managedContext`.

Has anybody an idea if that is possible?
Is it possible to "instantiate the AppDelegate" of my App or something like that?

**Update:** How to access core data within an app **and** an extension: The solution for this is to use AppGroup container.

Comment: You don't need to have an application delegate to use Core Data. The two are completely unrelated.

Comment: @TomHarrington do you mind expanding on that, as an answer for the question? :)

Answer (score 5):

Using Core Data has nothing to do with whether there is an application delegate. They are two separate things. You **can** put them together but neither Core Data nor the application delegate requires that. It's not even very good design to do so. The app delegate's job is to respond to app life-cycle events like launching, going into the background, etc, and it's bad design to also mix in the separate job of managing the app's data.

If you create a new project in Xcode and check the "use Core Data" box, Xcode will include methods in the app delegate class to set up Core Data for the app. But **that code can go in any class**. There's nothing special about the app delegate that requires that code to be in that class. Just because Xcode puts that code in that class doesn't mean that it's **necessary** to do it that way. If you need to use Core Data in an app extension, that's what you'll do.

One common approach is to create a new class to manage Core Data. Put all your Core Data stack management code there, instead of in the app delegate. The app delegate might create an instance of this class in your app. In an app extension, the class can be instantiated wherever it's needed for the type of extension.

Comment: Thanks @TomHarrington, meanwhile I understand that an AppDelegate is not necessary. But to access the data from an extension an AppGroup Container is necessary.

Comment: @KevinLieser true but your question specifically asked about what to do when there is no app delegate. Instantiating the app delegate, as you suggested, is not the right approach.

Comment: @TomHarrington, okay, so I'm faced with a slightly similar issue. I'd want to not use the storyboard for an iMessage app. How would I instantiate the view controller or rather the window?

Comment: @Shyam that's a different question than the one asked here. You should ask a new question rather that describes your situation more fully.

Comment: @TomHarrington, I seem to have found a way. Let me try if it works as expected. But, thanks for taking the time to respond. :)